# Script does not iterate through all objects properly

Tags: transforms, loop, transform-orientation

I'm writing a script that would set each selected object's orientation according to its normals. It works properly for a single selected object, but if multiple objects are selected, it iterates through all of them (I've confirmed it visually with lines commented out), but only affects the active one. Setting the current object as active in every iteration didn't work.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Euler
from mathutils import Vector
from math import degrees
import bpy, bmesh
import time

print('__________')
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=0, rotation=0, scale=1)
s_mesh_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
v_world = Vector((0,0,1))
v_neg = Vector((-1,-1,-1))

for obj in s_mesh_objects:
    
    #bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    polycount = len(obj.data.polygons)
    sum = Vector((0, 0, 0))

    for face in obj.data.polygons:
        
        n = face.normal
        #print(face.index, ' face normal: ', x)
        sum = sum + n

    avg = Vector(sum)
    avg.normalize()
    avg.x = round(avg.x, 6)
    avg.y = round(avg.y, 6)
    avg.z = round(avg.z, 6)
    print(' ')
    print('average normal: ', avg, ' of ', polycount, ' vectors')

    rotation = avg.rotation_difference(v_world).to_euler()
    if ((avg.angle(v_world)) > 0.0001):
    
        rotation.x = round(rotation.x, 6)
        rotation.y = round(rotation.y, 6)
        rotation.z = round(rotation.z, 6)

        print('rotation: ', [degrees(a) for a in rotation])
        obj.rotation_euler.x += rotation.x
        obj.rotation_euler.y += rotation.y
        obj.rotation_euler.z += rotation.z
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=0, rotation=1, scale=0)
        
        #bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
        #time.sleep(0.2)
        
        obj.rotation_euler.x -= rotation.x
        obj.rotation_euler.y -= rotation.y
        obj.rotation_euler.z = rotation.z
    
        print('rotation 2: ', [degrees(a) for a in (Vector(rotation)*v_neg)])
        #bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
        #time.sleep(0.7)
    
print('-----')
```

(Sorry if the code is a bit messy)

Comment: Fixed it using ChatGPT:

`for obj in s_mesh_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select_set(True)
    reset_orientation(obj)`

The code is in `reset_orientation()`. Still no idea why it works this way and not the other